# Java network with server-client in single model

Tags: java

I want to create a network with 3 nodes that communicate with each other. In more detail what I'm trying is to:

- Create a server-client model as a single project then copy the project in 2 more and there i have my 3 nodes
- By changing the ports ofcourse i can make them communicate even if I split the projects in different computers
- after that I want from one project to send the time (with some made-up time lag) to the other 2 nodes and vice-verca from the other 2 nodes, and then find the average time.
- I dont want to create single servers and single clients, I want to use threads to make a unified server-client that runs with a simple "run".

The problems I'm having are that the node that starts first also finishes first and the rest nodes are left hanging and in an endless loop. And also other that that I'm stuck with no idea what to do.

so far i have made this:

**Server:**

```
public class Server implements Runnable{
    private int port;
    private String name;

    public Server(int port, String name){
        this.port=port;
        this.name=name;
    }
    public synchronized void run(){
        while(true){
        try{

            Thread.sleep(5000);

            method();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return;
        }

        }
    }

    public synchronized void method() throws Exception{
        double sum=0;
        double average=0;
        double[] values = new double[10];
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);

      Socket s=server.accept();

      InputStream in= s.getInputStream();
      OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

      PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(out);
      Scanner r = new Scanner(in);
      for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      String msg = r.next();
      sum = Double.parseDouble(msg);
      values[i] = sum;

    }
      for(int j=0; j<values.length; j++){
          average = average + values[j];
      }
      System.out.println(name+": "+average/10);
}
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class Client implements Runnable{
    private int port;
    private int id;
    public Client(int port,int id){
        this.port=port;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public synchronized void run(){

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            method();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return;
        }

    }

    public synchronized void method() throws Exception{
        int num=0;
        Random ran = new Random(10);
        int d = 0;
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", port);

        InputStream in= s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(out);
        Scanner r = new Scanner(in);
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        d = ran.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("Client "+id+" sent "+d);
        w.println(d);
        w.flush();
        }


    }
}
```

**And i run them like this:**

```
public class Networks {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server s = new Server(5000, "Server 0");
        Server s2 = new Server(5001, "Server 1");
        Client c = new Client(5002, 11);
        Client c2 = new Client(5004, 22);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(s);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(c);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(c2);
        Thread t4 = new Thread(s2);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();

        try{
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t4.join();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("something");
        }

    }
}
```

You may ignore the ports and stuff since i have created the same project 2 more times for testing. Also the method() method is just for testing and i do get results back but when i run all 3 projects from the output i get that the first project's clients send nothing and i get results from both servers, the second's  clients works only 1 and i get only 1 server result and at the third project only the clients send but servers return nothing. An when the output is done the first project completes and ends and the other 2 run for ever.

Comment: I've asked this so many times, I think I'll ask it in old english. Some code, thy question shall illuminate, else thou shall walk the path of unknowing, forever shadowed in thy ignorance of the light.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

1. You're swallowing the exceptions in the client.
2. You're starting all 4 threads at the same time.
3. There is a race condition where a client can start and try to send on a socket before the server is listening/accepting
4. when the server does come up, the client has already errored out and the server waits forever.

This is just a theory, but it looks like it's probably the case.